# try to save nmap result to txt file

Tags: bash, output, nmap

I try to save results from nmap scan to a txt file. I use this command

`nmap -n -Pn  -p T:3389 -T5 -sS -iR 0 | grep "scan" | awk '{ print $5 }' > test.txt`

`cat test.txt`

the output looks like this :

```
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
```

It is working perfectly.

I want to scan only for open ports, and for this I try to use the `--open` option like this :

`nmap -n -Pn  -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS -iR 0 | grep "scan" | awk '{ print $5 }' > test.txt`

It does not work, the test.txt is empty. I try to use `tail -f test.txt` to see live results, but it's not working. Can someone explain what I'm doing, wrong?

I was expecting to see the result as the first time.

```
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx
```

after I want to add the port number after all ip like this

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:3389
xx.xx.xx.xx:3389
xx.xx.xx.xx:3389
xx.xx.xx.xx:3389
xx.xx.xx.xx:3389
xx.xx.xx.xx:3389
```

and for that I want to use `sed -i s/$/:3389/ test.txt`

I wonder if it is possible to get this result with only one command.

I try something like this :

`nmap -n -Pn -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS 192.168.0.1/24 | grep "scan" | awk '{ print $5 }' > test.txt; sed -i s/$/:3389/ test.txt`

`cat test.txt` and this is the result :

```
192.168.0.2:3389
192.168.0.16:3389
addresses:3389
```

I do not know why addresses:3389 appear at the end. But this works.

I want to get the same result but whit this command :

`nmap -n -Pn  -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS -iR 0 | grep "scan" | awk '{ print $5 }' > test.txt; sed -i s/$/:3389/ test.txt`

I try this command but not working. I want to use this command in a bash script. any help or suggestion is appreciated.

`nmap -n -Pn -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS -iR 0`

This is the output:

```
    Nmap scan report for 187.3.104.223
    Host is up (0.29s latency).

    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server

    Nmap scan report for 118.89.215.203
    Host is up (0.29s latency).

    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
```

Comment: you sure the ports are open?

Comment: If i use only this command `nmap -n -Pn  -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS -iR 0` it's working  , but if I try to save the result on a txt file. it doesn't work

Comment: What is the output of `nmap -n -Pn -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS -iR 0` ? Maybe there is no `scan` word in the output, or the `awk` command picks up the wrong column. We can't tell if you don't show the output.

Comment: `nmap -n -Pn -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS -iR 0`


    Nmap scan report for 187.3.104.223

    Host is up (0.29s latency).

    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server

    Nmap scan report for 118.89.215.203
    Host is up (0.29s latency).

    PORT     STATE SERVICE
   3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server.


In the output it is a scan  `Nmap scan report for 187.3.104.223`

Comment: `-iR` means "scan random addresses." There's no guarantee you will get results in any consistent time, because you may scan thousands of addresses before you find one that has 3389 open.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work. This is the command :

`nmap -n -Pn -p T:3389 -T5 -sS -iR 5000 --open | grep scan | grep -v addresses | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/$/:3389/' > test`

`cat test`

The output:

```
35.190.27.36:3389
35.214.139.176:3389
132.190.70.226:3389
109.228.13.61:3389
103.10.175.4:3389
113.134.99.14:3389
35.168.9.215:3389
167.93.112.130:3389
115.220.6.216:3389
137.32.209.1:3389
35.206.198.136:3389
```

I can change the `-iR 5000` if i need it, and it still works. It doesn't work with 0

I hope to be helpful if someone need it. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The "addresses" is from the summary ending line of the Nmap output, 5th word:

```
   Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (10 hosts up) scanned in 3.12 seconds
```

To remove the addresses from the output run:

```
   nmap -n -Pn -p T:3389 --open -T5 -sS -iR 0 |grep scan|grep -v addresses|awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/$/:3389/' > test.txt
```

Post your output if it's not what you expected / wanted to get

Comment: it doesn't work, I don't get anything in test.txt. but if I remove `--open` it works perfectly